# It failed when I try 'git push heroku master'

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, heroku

When I run the comand `git push heroku master` on my terminal, it returns me this error:

```
remote: error during build:
remote: Error: [vite]: Rollup failed to resolve import "main.js" from "index.html".
remote: This is most likely unintended because it can break your application at runtime.
```

and in my "index.html" the line that import "main.js" is this:

```
<script type="module" src="main.js"></script>
```

Comment: Do you have a `main.js`?

Comment: try changing the type to script not module